# claimsResponse Always Return Null

Tags: c#, dotnetopenauth

hello i have a following code in asp.net. i have used DotNetOpenAuth.dll for openID. the code is under

```
protected void openidValidator_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        // This catches common typos that result in an invalid OpenID Identifier.
        args.IsValid = Identifier.IsValid(args.Value);
    }

    protected void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.Page.IsValid)
        {
            return; // don't login if custom validation failed.
        }
        try
        {
            using (OpenIdRelyingParty openid = this.createRelyingParty())
            {
                IAuthenticationRequest request = openid.CreateRequest(this.openIdBox.Text);

                // This is where you would add any OpenID extensions you wanted
                // to include in the authentication request.
                ClaimsRequest objClmRequest = new ClaimsRequest();
                objClmRequest.Email = DemandLevel.Request;
                objClmRequest.Country = DemandLevel.Request;
                request.AddExtension(objClmRequest);

                // Send your visitor to their Provider for authentication.
                request.RedirectToProvider();
            }
        }
        catch (ProtocolException ex)
        {
            this.openidValidator.Text = ex.Message;
            this.openidValidator.IsValid = false;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.openIdBox.Focus();
        if (Request.QueryString["clearAssociations"] == "1")
        {
            Application.Remove("DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.ApplicationStore");

            UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
            builder.Query = null;
            Response.Redirect(builder.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
        }

        OpenIdRelyingParty openid = this.createRelyingParty();
        var response = openid.GetResponse();
        if (response != null)
        {
            switch (response.Status)
            {
                case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
                    // This is where you would look for any OpenID extension responses included
                    // in the authentication assertion.
                    var claimsResponse = response.GetExtension<ClaimsResponse>();
                    State.ProfileFields = claimsResponse;
                    // Store off the "friendly" username to display -- NOT for username lookup
                    State.FriendlyLoginName = response.FriendlyIdentifierForDisplay;
                    // Use FormsAuthentication to tell ASP.NET that the user is now logged in,
                    // with the OpenID Claimed Identifier as their username.
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(response.ClaimedIdentifier, false);
                    break;
                case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled:
                    this.loginCanceledLabel.Visible = true;
                    break;
                case AuthenticationStatus.Failed:
                    this.loginFailedLabel.Visible = true;
                    break;

                // We don't need to handle SetupRequired because we're not setting
                // IAuthenticationRequest.Mode to immediate mode.
                ////case AuthenticationStatus.SetupRequired:
                ////    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private OpenIdRelyingParty createRelyingParty()
    {
        OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
        int minsha, maxsha, minversion;
        if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["minsha"], out minsha))
        {
            openid.SecuritySettings.MinimumHashBitLength = minsha;
        }
        if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["maxsha"], out maxsha))
        {
            openid.SecuritySettings.MaximumHashBitLength = maxsha;
        }
        if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["minversion"], out minversion))
        {
            switch (minversion)
            {
                case 1: openid.SecuritySettings.MinimumRequiredOpenIdVersion = ProtocolVersion.V10; break;
                case 2: openid.SecuritySettings.MinimumRequiredOpenIdVersion = ProtocolVersion.V20; break;
                default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("minversion");
            }
        }
        return openid;
    }
```

for above code i am always getting

```
var claimsResponse = response.GetExtension<ClaimsResponse>();
```

i am always getting claimsResponse= null. what is the reason why it happen. is there any requirement which is required for openid like domain validation for RelyingParty?? please give me answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is a repost of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311726/claimsresponse-always-return-null. More details are provided in this post, but still...

Comment: While we're at it: why is this an answer instead of a comment? :P
(I've voted to close the other question as this one was more informative)